# Default SpringbootApplication for all SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

So, i have two classes annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which are loaded based on a feature toggle. Dont ask for reasons. It is needed. Everything works as expected. Except of the SpringbootTests. I have now to decalare always which SpringBootApplication class should be used. So instead of ...

```
@SpringBootTest
```

... i have always to write that:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplicationToUse.class)
```

otherwise i get this error:

> [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [org.bla.foo.ThisIsSomeTest]: ThisIsSomeTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.

Is it somehow possible to configure a default config class for all SpringBootTest's? For example in the test profile config or do i have to change all `@SpringBootTest` to `@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringBootApplicationToUse.class)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. 
One of the classes which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` needs the `@ConditionalOnProperty` attribute with `matchIfMissing = true`:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "application.feature.somefeature", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@SpringBootApplication
```

This indicates, that this `@SpringBootApplication` is used, if the property is missing in the application settings (which it is somehow in case of `@SpringBootTest` ).